# How to replace @ using sed c0mmand?

Tags: sed

I have the following header :

```
@SRR1561197.1/1
@SRR1561197.2/1 
@SRR1561197.3/1
@SRR1561197.4/1
```

I want to Add few letters after @ and before SRR like this:

```
@MexD1SRR1561197.1/1
@MexD1SRR1561197.2/1 
@MexD1SRR1561197.3/1
@MexD1SRR1561197.4/1
```

I tried:

```
sed 's/@/@MexD1/File,fastq > change.fastq
```

This results in empty file..

Comment: do you read some sed tutorial ? quote are not close, `@` have no special meaning in sed or regex and `s///` catch a new way of working with a new keyword `file`, ...   (http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sed with the in file replacement option. The `g` at the end makes it global.

`sed -i 's/@/@MexD1/g' file`

To fix your code.

`sed 's/@/@MexD1/g' File.fastq > change.fastq`

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape it: **sed s/\@/\@MexD1/g source-file-name >  change.fastq**

Comment: why `@`need to be escaped ? what is the normal behaviour in sed action ?

Comment: No need to escape @, i suggested that as normal behavior doesn't work for the user. If you use @ instead of / as separator - escape it

Comment: not clear in your post and the goal here is not to show what is not working but how to make it work (if possible)

Comment: Sure Neron, I'm new here.. I will remember that